# how to connect mongodb server using Java Script

Tags: javascript, mongodb

am very new to both mongodb and java script.
Now i need to connect to my local mongodb instance using java script in order to get the list of documents.

any help?,
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mongoose to connect to a mongoDB database : http://mongoosejs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at here,

https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
 , Server = require('mongodb').Server;

var mongoClient = new MongoClient(new Server('localhost', 27017));
mongoClient.open(function(err, mongoClient) {
  var db1 = mongoClient.db("mydb");

 mongoClient.close();
});
```

Comment: Hi Mukund, when i try the above code its throwing an error saying that it cannot find monodb module. The error: module.js:338
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'mongodb'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/hadoop/Desktop/testing.js:1:81)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)

Comment: have you started mongodb? ie, goto terminal/cmd and type mongod, then try it again

Answer (score 0):

In order to connect to database, you need to connect your application to a server( not sure if the application could connect to database directly but from what I learnt, it seems server side language is needed). Thus, if you want to connect to database with javascript only, you may consider using node.js+express to connect to mongoDb. [I think this link is quite useful. I also learnt from this website.](http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2014/restful-web-app-node-express-mongodb/) This website teaches you how to do that from scratch and instructions can be easily followed. If you prefer to use php for server side, [I just googled this website which might help.](http://www.pronique.com/blog/installing-mongodb-on-windows-the-wamp-way) It seems to me that php is easier to learn but if you only need basic CRUD operation, the website mentioned is enough.